# Is there a straight line that intersects both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ perpendicularly?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Is there a straight line that intersects both curves $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=\cos(x)$ perpendicularly?
(Like shown in this picture)

[image: sketch of the idea]

I feel like it should work, because of the fact that the derivative of the sine is the cosine and they intersect, so they are definitely parallel at some point, but I'm not entirely sure how to prove whether or not the perpendicular lines actually match.
I've googled around but I haven't found anything about this idea.

Comment: Sorry, but your wording is unclear.  Do you perhaps mean that given curves $y = \sin x$ and $y = \cos x$, is there a straight line that intersects both curves perpendicularly?  This is what I gather from your illustration.

Comment: what is a “lot” ?

Comment: If it matters any, for example line $y = 1.0931697 x - 2.5757205$ intersects $\cos(x)$ at $x = 1.9866519$ and $\sin(x)$ at $x = 2.7257371$, both at $y = \pm 0.4039727$ with slopes $-0.9147710 \approx -1/1.0931697$, and therefore the line intersects the curves perpendicularly.  Because of periodicity and symmetry, there are an infinite number of such lines with slopes $\pm 1.0931697$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson a lot is a line that intersects another line perpendicularly, I didn't know the correct word since I'm not a native speaker, and Google Translate translated it as "lot"...

Comment: Yes, @Glärbo that's exactly what I mean. Sorry for my unclear question, I'm not a native speaker and it's hard to get math phrases down correctly in other languages

Comment: In English, a line that cuts a curve perpendicularly is called a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)). So the normal at a point is perpendicular to the tangent at that point. Eg, a radius of a circle is normal to the circle

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks! so could the question be phrased as "do sine and cosine have a common(/shared) normal?" instead?

Comment: Yes, you could phrase it that way, but I think it's quite clear in its current form. Although "normal" is a perfectly valid term in geometry, it can be a bit confusing, even for native speakers, because of the other meaning of "normal". ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume from your image that a "lot" is **a line perpendicular to a curve**. Please clarify if this is indeed the definition you're using since as it's written now your question is not clear.

---

The line perpendicular to $\sin(x)$ at $x=a$ is given by
$$
y = -\sec(a)x + \left[\sin(a) +\sec(a)a \right] \tag{1}
$$
which can be derived recalling that the perpendicular slope is given by $-\frac{1}{\text{Slope}}$ and that the slope of the tangent line is the derivative. Similarly, the line perpendicular to $\cos(x)$ at $x=b$ is given by
$$
y = \csc(b)x + \left[\cos(b)-\csc(b)b \right] \tag{2}
$$
Our question then becomes knowing when $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal. For them to be equal, their slope and their $y$-intercept must be equal simultaneously. From equating the slopes we get that
\begin{align}
-\sec(a) =  \csc(b) & \implies \frac{1}{\cos(a)} + \frac{1}{\sin(b)} = 0\\
& \implies \frac{\sin(b)+\cos(a)}{\sin(b)\cos(a)} = 0\\
& \implies \cos(a) = -\sin(b)\\
& \implies \cos(a) = \cos\left(b+ \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
& \implies b = \pm a - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{3}
\end{align}
where we obtain the $\pm$ recalling that $\cos(x)$ is an even function. From here we'll use the condition that the $y$-intercepts of $(1)$ and $(2)$ must be equal to conclude where the lines can be equal. We see that
\begin{align}
\sin(a) +\sec(a)a  &= \cos(b)-\csc(b)b \\
& \overset{(3)}{=} \cos\left(\pm a - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k\right)+\sec(a)\left(\pm a - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k\right)\\
& = \pm\sin(a)+\sec(a)\left(\pm a - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k\right)
\end{align}
We'll notice here that the choice of the "$+$" sign leaves no solutions as we would arrive at $\sec(a) = 0$, which has no solutions. This means our solutions are given by $a\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
&\sin(a) +\sec(a)a  = -\sin(a)+\sec(a)\left(- a - \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k\right)\\
\implies& 2 \left[\sin(a) +\sec(a)a \right] = \sec(a)\left(2 \pi k - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)\\
\implies& \boxed{2a + \sin(2a) = 2 \pi k - \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} }
\end{align}
So there are an *infinite number* of lines that are perpendicular to both $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ at the same time, one for each integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

The above equation doesn't have an analytic solution for $a$, but you can approximate the values numerically. In fact, your drawing corresponds to the value of $a$ satisfying $2a + \sin(2a) = \frac{3\pi}{2}$, and you'll find that the [numerical solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+a+%2B+sin%282+a%29+%3D+%283+%CF%80%29%2F2) gives $a \approx 2.725737$, hence your green line has an approximate equation of $y = -\sec( 2.725737)x + \left[\sin( 2.725737) +\sec( 2.725737)( 2.725737) \right]$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by a "lot". I'm sorry, Google Translate doesn't seem to be accurate with math terms. Thank you for your answer!